# Creating even ranges based on values in an oracle table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, partition

I have a big table which is 100k rows in size and the PRIMARY KEY is of the datatype NUMBER. The way data is populated in this column is using a random number generator.

So my question is, can there be a possibility to have a SQL query that can help me with getting partition the table evenly with the range of values. Eg: If my column value is like this:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

And I would like this to be broken into three partitions, then I would expect an output like this:

```
Range 1          1-3
Range 2          4-7
Range 3          8-10
```

Comment: Do you mean physically rebuilding the table as a partitioned table, or do you just want a query that will return the data in three sets? `mod(your_pk_column,3)` will return 0, 1 or 2 if you just want a third of the data.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: I do not want to rebuild my table as partition but get an idea of how should i define a range based on the number of partition I select to break the table. I mean, if my table has **100 records** and I want to break it into **5 partition**, I know each and every partition will have 20 records, but I would really like to get the exact start and end point based on the column data for a particular partition.

Comment: Is it important that the PK values within the groups are sequential, given that as the values are assigned randomly? For example, `mod(id,3)` would give three groupings as `{3,6,9}`, `{1,4,7,10}`, `{2,5,8}`. Would that do, or does it have to be `{1,2,3}`, `{4,5,6}` etc?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the `WIDTH_BUCKET()` function. [Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions250.htm#SQLRF06163)

This query will give you the start and end range for a table of 1250 rows split into 20 buckets based on `id`:

```
with bkt as (
    select id
           , width_bucket(id, 1, 1251, 20) as id_bucket
    from t23
)
select id_bucket
       , min(id) as bkt_start
       , max(id) as bkt_end
       , count(*)
from bkt
group by id_bucket
order by 1
;
```

The two middle parameters specify min and max values; the last parameter specifies the number of buckets. The output is the rows between the minimum and maximum bows split as evenly as possible into the specified number of buckets. Be careful with the min and max parameters; I've found poorly chosen bounds can have an odd effect on the split.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This actually helps. Can you please tell me how can I transform the above column, if my PK column is a varchar or GUID?

Comment: One of the reasons why software is a marvellous thing is that it allows us to experiment. We can try something, write some code, see what happens. The cool thing is that whatever happens we have learned something. Experimentation costs nothing except some time.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works without `width_bucket` function. While it is more verbose and certainly less efficient it will split the data as evenly as possible, even if some ID values are missing.

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
 SELECT rownum AS id
   FROM dual 
CONNECT BY level <= 10;

WITH
   data AS (
      SELECT id, rownum as row_num
        FROM t
   ),
   total AS (
      SELECT count(*) AS total_rows
        FROM data
   ),
   parts AS (
      SELECT rownum as part_no, total.total_rows, total.total_rows / 3 as part_rows
        FROM dual, total 
     CONNECT BY level <= 3
   ),
   bounds AS (
      SELECT parts.part_no, 
             parts.total_rows, 
             parts.part_rows, 
             COALESCE(LAG(data.row_num) OVER (ORDER BY parts.part_no) + 1, 1) AS start_row_num,
             data.row_num AS end_row_num
       FROM data
       JOIN parts 
         ON data.row_num = ROUND(parts.part_no * parts.part_rows, 0)
   )
SELECT bounds.part_no, d1.ID AS start_id, d2.ID AS end_id
  FROM bounds
  JOIN data d1
    ON d1.row_num = bounds.start_row_num
  JOIN data d2
    ON d2.row_num = bounds.end_row_num
ORDER BY bounds.part_no;

   PART_NO   START_ID     END_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          3
         2          4          7
         3          8         10
```